# Application.Screenupdating and Windows 7

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

If I run this snippet of code on my Windows XP machine (Either xl2003 or xl2010), I get a 'trail' when I drag the form around the screen - which I realize is normal.  However, if I run the same code on my Windows 7 (64 bit) machine, it does NOT leave a trail, as I would expect.

Has something changed in Windows 7 that causes this?  Unfortunately, this masks a potential problem in applications that are developed on the Win7 machine, but won't show up until run on an older OS machine.

I've done a lot of searching on the internet, but so far no mention of this.

Comment: I'm running on Win7 (64 bit) and it is showing trail on mine (XL2013). I cannot replicate what you've described.

Comment: If I use an aero theme on Windows 7: no trails. If I use a basic theme on Windows 7: trails. Try right-clicking on the desktop, choose Personalize and swap to a basic theme

Comment: @barrowc, That did it, thanks.  I'd have been a long time finding that one.

Comment: I'd imagine it's because the rules for screen updating are being run at an OS level for the theme (aero uses transparency if I remember, which would require screen refreshing for the frosted glass effect), and your code is only setting the screen updating flag at an application level. If the theme requires screen updating then the OS overrides the application, as it rightly should.

Comment: @SO, thanks for the explanation, I know very little about aero themes, but at least now I have some awareness of possible side effects.

Comment: @SierraOscar Now that I'm running Win 10 I'm back to square one with this, none of the settings I've tried seem to have any affect.  Would appreciate any further suggestions you might have, thanks.